# Comparing File datetime with destination file datetime

Tags: batch-file

I am having an question. 
I need something that compares files in an certain dir and compare the datetime of those files to the datetime of files that are located inside an other dir.

Example

```
FOR /R "e:\folder" %%A IN (*.*) DO (
    set filedatetime=%%~tA
    FOR /R "e:\folder2" %%B IN (*.res.gz) DO (
        set filedatetime2=%%~tB
    )
)
IF %filedatetime% == %filedatetime2% GOTO SAME
GOTO NOSAME
```

However its not working like i would like.
Does anyone has an example so i can use it.

Comment: _"However its not working like i would like."_ How is it working then? Why do you think this is? P.S., you're searching for more file extensions in your outer loop. Why?

Comment: Well for the other FOR loop is ment to set the filedatetime2 for the files it needs to compare.

So we have file 1 with date and time and it must compare it to file 2 with date and time only then its an .gz file.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what is asked, but ...

```
for /r "e:\folder" %%a in (*.*) do for /r "e:\folder2" %%b in (*.res.gz) do (
    if "%%~ta"=="%%~tb" (
        echo SAME %%~fa %%~fb
    ) else (
        echo NOT SAME %%~fa %%~fb
    )
)
```

This will check all files under "e:\folder" against all `.res.gz` files under "e:\folder2" and for each pair report if both files have the same timestamp or not.

Answer (score 1):

give it a try:

```
FOR /R "e:\folder" %%A IN (*.*) DO (
    FOR /R "e:\folder2" %%B IN (*.res.gz) DO (
        if "%%~tA"=="%%~tB" (GOTO:SAME) else GOTO:NOSAME
    )
)
```